# What's the diference between 물어보다 and 물어봐요

Tags: vocabulary, difference

What's the diference between 물어보다 and 물어봐요, would you like to give me examples too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I can't leave a comment so I am writhing as an answer. My info is not expert but I can tell you the difference as a native Korean. When you search the dictionary, you can find the verbs with the form of

- 물어보다
- 달리다
- 마시다

These are the basic form of verbs, but we don't use this form on our real life. In Korean language, we change the end by the situations. For example, for `물어보다`, it changes to `물어볼래` `물어보지 마` `물어서` `물었지만`...etc. I'm sorry for you but there are so many kinds of ending words(어미 in Korean).

`물어보다` = `ask`

> 안내원에게 물어보다.

Of course, you can make an example like this, but it sounds like so rigid, and you can only find these examples in the dictionary or selection when you play the game.

`물어봐요` can be translated as `please ask`.

> 저는 잘 모르겠어요. 민수에게 물어봐요. / I don't know. Please ask 민수.

Comment: so 물어봐요 is just the conjugated form of 물어보다 because is the steam form of the verb "to ask"?

Comment: Yes, You can think that way.

Answer (score 0):

1.
묻다 and 물어보다 are similar in the dictionary. Both means asking others to know or reveal something. 
But each word can be used differently 
because 묻다 has another meaning to ask others to call a person to account or charge a person with responsibility.

For example,
길을 물어보다 = 길을 묻다 = ask the direction

관리자에게 책임을 묻다 = charge the manager with responsibility

2.
물어봐요 = 물어보아요 = 물어보다 + -아요 
-아요 = -아- + -요
-아- is an ending of a word 어미
-요 is 보조사 sub-postposional word

-아요 means asking, suggesting and ordering. 
So 물어봐요 can be different according to situation.